# QuickBooks Desktop SDK - Is it possible to always open a new company file when making a call with the QuickBooks SDK?

Tags: process, sdk, quickbooks, usersession

Is it possible to always open a new instance of QuickBooks when making a call to a specific company file using the desktop SDK?

I am trying to use a server that is shared by many people to interact with QuickBooks, so it typically has a number of qb32 processes open.  When I make a connection using that server, it tries to use one of those to process the request (which I don't want).

Best case is that my SDK request opens a new primary QuickBooks instance in a specific user session on the server, or that it opens it in no user session, so that it can run like a windows service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't able to open company file without quick books instant (QB32.exe) installed in local machine. and also we cant able to open two instance on different company file at a time in same machine.

Comment: one more thing is here since you use SDK it run QB32 process on back end you can check it with Task manager